If you are working remotely as a contractor, can you be allowed to applying as a business vistor to Australia?
I'm a remote software engineer based in Vietnam, a contractor, invited by my client (an Australian entity) to visit/working in Australia in February for 2 weeks. And my finding is that the subclass 600 business visitor stream seems to be most suitable for me. I will need an invitation letter from my client to apply for visa.
Now, my client has concerns that technically business visitor isn't supposed to "work". So they have troubles in providing me the invitation letter. I have an agency that tells me because our relationship is client and contractor/freelancer. "Work" in their definition is joining the Australian workforce, staying at a certain workplace, and working for a certain time for the employer. And I'm not doing that, I'm just going there, visiting/providing software advice as a foreign contractor, not an employee. My client and I have already working together for more than a year by banking paper trail, proof by contract. It proves that my work started before I came to Australia. So I'm good.
But because I can't really find this definition of "work" anywhere on the official Australian site. I would love if anyone has any advice for me or something to verify this.
Edit: Thank everyone who has come to answer this. I'm getting it now that  "business visitor" is only doing business visitor activities now and not supposed to actually working.

Don’t know the specifics for Australia but they’re probably similar to the US and elsewhere: you are not coming to work but to meet your client, define the next steps for your work, negotiate contracts, etc. You won’t be writing a line of code, only exchanging on what you should be working on when you are back home. If your intent is to actually write code while you’re there, then indeed it’s probably not the appropriate visa. Basically all of your working time while in Australia should be meetings with your customer. If you start spending time alone writing software, you’re working.

Note: to avoid confusion: not being employed by an Australian company doesn't matter. Also contractor/freelancer is not relevant. As the other comment (and answer): it matter what you do (and where).

You said your client has concerns, and it seems to me that it's up to your client to overcome this by advising you (in writing/email) what visa you require.

"Not employed by an Australian company" is actually better. In other countries (especially US) it's is forbidden to receive payment from the host country. If you were an employee of an Australian company they could argue that you were. If you are an independent contractor then you aren't. (You are being paid by your own company).

@DJClayworth "You are being paid by your own company": maybe not.  If the independent contractor operates as a sole proprietor then there is no separate company; the individual receives the client's payment directly.  Whether this is significant under Australian law, I do not know.  It's not even entirely clear to me whether the question is settled in US law, but there are certainly some situations in which the executive branch has adopted the interpretation that it is.

@StephenG-HelpUkraine what if the client is wrong?  Then the contractor has a negative immigration history, which will affect him for the rest of his life -- if not in Australia then in the UK and any other country that asks "have you ever been denied a visa or admission to any country?"  It is better to take one's own immigration advice.  It is a business expense, just as with the airfare, accommodation, meals, etc.

@phoog If you take this view then only the Australian immigration authorities can advise the OP.  I don't think it's unreasonable to expect the company to know the situation, and it may even be a legal responsibility at least partly held by the company to ensure the correct visa is applied for,

Permitted business visitor activities are described here

As a business visitor, you can:

make general business or employment enquiries
investigate, negotiate, enter into or review a business contract
conduct activities as part of an official government visit
take part in a conference, trade fair or seminar. You can’t be paid by the organisers to take part
undertake tourist activities



You can't:

work for or provide services to a business or organisation based in Australia
sell goods or services directly to the public


So as @jcaron says in a comment, if you will be spending all your time discussing work you are/will be doing back home, you’re fine.
However, IMHO “providing software advice” while you’re on site would be providing a service, and so would not be a permitted activity.

I'm not familiar with Australian law, but in the US providing training as part of other services is allowed. And I think "providing software advice" is likely to be allowable if its related to work you have done for the company. And the truth is that immigration are never going to check up on exactly what was done or said. As long as you keep that the line that you are discussing work you've already done or are going to you will be fine.

@jcaron I don’t disagree with you, however I do think the OP needs to be very clear about what activities he/she will be doing for the visa application and (assuming it’s approved) for any landing interview. The reluctance of the OP’s Australian client to provide an invitation is a red flag IMHO, as are the references to ‘work’.

My two cents on the topic: these kind of laws usually are there to avoid people circumventing immigration laws and performing unskilled labour in the country they are entering. This does not seem to be OP's case, and therefore he should be in the clear. Not legal advice of course, but even if you do write a few lines of code, nobody is going to care.

On a visitor visa giving or taking advice without sales/employment  should be permissible but it is better to confirm with a legal opinion.

@VladimirCravero that might be the legislative motivation, but enforcement agencies have been documents to ignore that intent and deny visas/entry to 'white collar' visitors.  OTOH, On the US, at least, no one is going to bother you about a two-week business trip, I can't speak for Australia.

@bmargulies Even in the US, the problem isn't what you do in your two weeks, the problem is being rejected at the border. And that does happen at US borders. They ask "purpose of the trip", and if you use the wrong words, they ask more questions.

Yes, this is exactly my experience. I know I always have to use the word business, not the word work, and I am always traveling for meetings anyway, which is acceptable. I have experience only in the US, though - I would be surprised if other countries have stricter rules... but being careful is never a bad idea.

@VladimirCravero "if you do write a few lines of code, nobody is going to care": True enough; just don't tell anybody.

The core requirement for that visum, no matter whether you clean toilets, configure an AI cluster or hand out spiritual advice: You cannot get paid for it. If you get paid, it's work. (And sorry, I cannot help myself: If you get laid, it's only work if you get paid! ;-) ) Therefore, the visa application should be strictly designed to make clear that this is not a work trip but e.g. contract negotiations and the like (meetings before work starts). That may be a difficult or impossible thing to do given your previous and ongoing contractual relationship.

And I know from personal experience as a freelancer with an American partner that the legacy regulations are not aligning well with the modern realities of a global economy (and relationships). I mean, where am I even working when I am in a foreign country remotely logging in to a server in a different country and live in a third??

I suggest you use the Australian Immigration visa finder.
https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-finder
I think you are doing "highly skilled - specialised work", expect to stay for "up to 3 months". There is 1 visa that meets these criteria:
"Subclass 400
Temporary Work (Short Stay Specialist) visa"
Processing time if submitted today is 50% (of applications) processed in 10 days, 90% processed in 20 days"

I know about this visa. But I feel like it's kinda an overkill with more paperwork and even more complex implications (that my client has to pay me Australian wage, kinda beat the point of outsourcing). And it's only 2 weeks stay. So I'm mostly thinking just apply for the visitor visa and don't actually work.

@PhuongThaoNguyen in my (inexpert) opinion, your interpretation is reasonable, or better yet it is quite possibly the prevailing interpretation in Australia.  You've clearly given this a lot of thought.  But what you really need, it seems, is advice from someone who knows.  The most reliable way to get that advice is going to be to engage an Australian immigration lawyer.  If you really can avoid "actually working" then you ought to be fine, but it's in your interest to know where Australian immigration law draws the line between business activities and "actual work."

"Actual work" as a contractor is the time for which you get paid, as specified in the timesheet that you send to your client. That is how I (an international development consultant) report in my Australian Tax Return.

"my client has to pay me Australian wage" - I doubt this is correct. You are an independent contractor with a contract that states your conditions of engagement. The Australian Taxation Office has detailed rules about who an employee is (and so must be paid standard wages, given standard conditions) and who an independent contractor is. Your client will not vary your contract rate just because you go to Australia to do any of the work.
